# SQL left anti semi join equivalent query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, u-sql

I'm analyzing the [concept of anti semi-join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29) in the SQL Server,

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/statements-and-expressions/select/from/joins/antisemijoin#summary) that describes the keyword ANTISEMIJOIN of the U-SQL syntax quotes the following query for SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM A 
WHERE A.Key NOT IN (SELECT B.Key FROM B)
```

[Others](https://sqlchitchat.com/sqldev/tsql/semi-joins-in-sql-server/#Left_Anti_Semi_Join) suggest the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE A.Key = B.Key)
```

Both of them seem to return the same records, the query proposed by Microsoft seems to have better performance, however I found a case in which the two queries give different results and I don't know which of them is the right one. I show it with an example:

```
DECLARE @A TABLE ([OnA] [int], [DataA] [text])
DECLARE @B TABLE ([OnB] [int], [DataB] [text])

INSERT INTO @A VALUES (1, 'A1'), (2, 'A2'), (NULL, 'A3')
INSERT INTO @B VALUES (1, 'B1'), (3, 'B2'), (NULL, 'B3')

--LEFT SEMI-JOIN
SELECT * FROM @A 
WHERE OnA IN (SELECT OnB FROM @B)           
--Returns with ANSI_NULLS ON:  1 | A1              (Correct!)       
--Returns with ANSI_NULLS OFF: 1 | A1, NULL | A3   (Correct!)

SELECT * FROM @A 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @B WHERE OnA = OnB)  
--Returns with ANSI_NULLS ON:  1 | A1              (Correct!) 
--Returns with ANSI_NULLS OFF: 1 | A1              (Not correct!)("ANSI_NULLS OFF" insensitive!)

--LEFT ANTISEMI-JOIN
SELECT * FROM @A 
WHERE OnA NOT IN (SELECT OnB FROM @B)                
--Returns with ANSI_NULLS ON:  empty               (Not Correct and very dangerous!)                 
--Returns with ANSI_NULLS OFF: 2 | A2              (Correct!)

SELECT * FROM @A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @B WHERE OnA = OnB) 
--Returns with ANSI_NULLS ON:  2 | A2, NULL | A3   (Correct!)
--Returns with ANSI_NULLS OFF: 2 | A2, NULL | A3   (Not correct!)("ANSI_NULLS OFF" insensitive!)
```

It's evident that with the presence of NULL in the correspondence of the key columns, the query *left antisemi-join* quoted by Microsoft doesn't return (in normal case: when ANSI_NULLS ON) the complementary result to the *left semi-join* query and this is already a bug. In addition, zero records return always, it's very serious!

On the other hand, the other formulas with the EXIST and NOT EXIST operator also don't seem to be consistent with the "ANSI_NULLS OFF" setting. This error affects also the results of the "left/right semi join" operations!

So, I assume that the "semi join" operation is ANSI_NULLS proof in T-SQL/SQL Server, but it should be done only in this way:

```
--LEFT SEMI-JOIN
SELECT * FROM @A 
WHERE OnA IN (SELECT OnB FROM @B)
```

While the "antisemi join" operation is not safe and not ANSI_NULLS proof, so we have the responsibility to use the right variant in certainly static contexts:

```
--LEFT ANTISEMI-JOIN (when ANSI_NULLS is ON)
SELECT * FROM @A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @B WHERE OnA = OnB)

--LEFT ANTISEMI-JOIN (when ANSI_NULLS is OFF and it's possible that there is at least one record with NULL in key value)
SELECT * FROM @A 
WHERE OnA NOT IN (SELECT OnB FROM @B)
```

Do you all agree with me?

These are my questions:

1. *Would it be right to handle the "NullVsNull" eventuality with SET ANSI_NULLS rather than an explicit query?*
2. *What would be the best single query to faithfully reflect the [ANTI SEMI JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29) behavior regardless of the setting ANSI_NULLS?*
3. *Is it possible that [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/statements-and-expressions/select/from/joins/antisemijoin#summary) and [Others](https://sqlchitchat.com/sqldev/tsql/semi-joins-in-sql-server/#Left_Anti_Semi_Join) are both making a mistake?*
4. *Why does the EXIST operator seem to be insensitive to "ANSI_NULLS OFF" setting?*
5. *Why does the NOT IN operator always return EMPTY in the fifth case?*

Comment: In MS SQL this is generally accepted as _By Design_ you can't and should not try to use Null comparison in this way when `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`. Nulls in this mode effectively excludes the null value records from comparison at all, unless you use IS NULL or coalescing functions. Use `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` if you want nulls to participate in direct value comparisons as values. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=SQL%20Server%20returns%20an%20error%20that%20lists%20all,no%20such%20indexes%20on%20the%20tables%20or%20views.

Comment: With SET ANSI_NULLS OFF the NullVsNull case is considered a match and I don't think it should be, on the contrary if I forget to set ANSI_NULLS OFF I would always get an empty list and that I think is even more dangerous. In my opinion, the query with the NOT EXISTS clause remains the most precise null-proof regardless of the ANSI_NULLS. So why didn't Microsoft mention this query? Perhaps the U-SQL engine mirrors the query with the NOT IN clause? I'd like to try..

Comment: I'm not suggesting that ANSI_NULLS OFF is a good solution, but its one that works, if nulls are involved use NOT EXISTS and or IS NOT NULL, or `COALESCE` the values that might be null (or `ISNULL`) to an arbitrary value to make comparisons work, you only asked why there is a difference, this isn't specifically acknowledged in the docs because it is inferred knowledged about JOIN and comparison logic in general for MS SQL Server, many of us build queries specifcally around this type of evaluation behaviour. (I usually `IsNull(expr, -1)` when I need to compare to an expected null value)

Comment: It's not a mistake or an error, this is by design. The following article explains: http://www.sqlbadpractices.com/using-not-in-operator-with-null-values/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists)

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface it is a great article but I haven't found yet all the answers, I updated the main question.

Answer (score 1):

You already understand the idea why it's happening. I found a good article in below link. Please check it out.

Microsoft might not have made a mistake. According to below article Microsoft SQL Server handles null differently than ANSI standard if you set `ansi_nulls` to off.

Use below line before your query

```
set ansi_nulls off
```

And `not in()` will return your desired result though there is null in the list.

For further reading:

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/four-rules-for-nulls

In the provided Microsoft's documentation they also mentioned:

> Consider using SEMIJOIN (U-SQL) for situations where you would use a
> subquery with IN in SQL. Consider using ANTISEMIJOIN (U-SQL) for
> situations where you would use a subquery with NOT IN in SQL

Comment: Link only answers on considered poor quality on this site and may get deleted. You need to quote the relevant part of the link such that the answer is stand along in the case of the links going down.

Comment: @DaleK I have removed screenshot. Since I am just roaming around fir couple of months may I know when to use images in answer?

Comment: @DaleK Is the answer appropriate now? Or it needs more clarity? Would really appreciate your valuable suggestion.

Comment: Microsoft's error may not have mentioned this conditionality of SET ANSI_NULLS OFF. Not a small mistake I would say...

Comment: They misrepresented null related infprmation in books online also.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur about the only time a screenshow is appropriate is if you are building a user interface and need to show how it looks. (Or for example showing the rendering of a SSRS report). Anything else should be appropriately formatted text.

Comment: @jangix - you should forget `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` exists.  Implementing that was a mistake made > 20 years ago. Just concentrate on standard SQL and, yes, the behaviour of `NOT IN` vs `NOT EXISTS` is different in the presence of nulls. As for which one, if any, mirrors the USQL behaviour I don't know

Answer (score 1):

First of all, here's a Fiddle to help play with all this:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/aa477/20

Now we can talk about what's going on. The answer here starts with a correct understanding of what `NULL` means.

People often think of `NULL` as meaning, "this value is empty", but this understanding is incomplete. It is better to think of `NULL` as meaning, "I don't know what this value is".

With the former (empty) understanding, comparing two `NULL` values (`{empty} == {empty}`) could be reasonably seen to produce `true`. But with the new correct (I don't know) understanding of `NULL`, we can see it makes much less sense to assume one {I don't know} will be equal to another {I don't know}. The correct answer to this comparison is more obviously still {I don't know}. Therefore `NULL == NULL` is still... `NULL`. Furthermore, `NULL` is **falsy** when forced into a boolean expression.

---

This is what the ANSI standard defines, what you should stick with pretty much all the time, and also the correct way to understand how `NULL` formally interacts with any of the mathematical/relational algebra join concepts.

---

If I really wanted to formally express this join type, I'd use the `NOT EXISTS()` variant. You could also write it like this:

```
SELECT @A.* 
FROM @A 
LEFT JOIN @B ON OnA = OnB
WHERE  @B.OnB IS NULL
```

We sometimes call this an Exclusion Join, but `NOT EXISTS()` also typically executes faster than the `LEFT JOIN`.

Again, for all of these options, understanding what is correct still hinges on a correct understanding of the `NULL` comparisons. Since the `NULL` from the `A3` row is *not known to be the same value* as the `NULL` from the `B3` row, that record should be included.

However, (and this is *important*), all this is in the theoretical abstract. In the practical concrete world, the correct result for your application depends on the meaning of the value. Sometimes a particular system, application, developer, or data model will decide `NULL` really does just mean "empty" for this purpose. Whether this is wise, or formally correct, is irrelevant. What is relevant is understanding the meaning of the data you're looking at and producing query results that answer the questions asked by your requirements.

---

There is still the question of whether this query shows a mistake or bug with Sql Server:

```
SELECT * FROM @A 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @B WHERE OnA = OnB)
```

With `ANSI_NULLS` on (the default), things are correct. We don't know the `NULL` values are the same, and so the record should not be included. However, we the same results when `ANSI_NULLS` are off, even though we'd expect the `NULL = NULL` comparison to include that row. You may be correct about a bug here, though people smarter than me may explain why it isn't. But if so, I'm not really bothered by it. In my opinion, if you turn off ANSI_NULLS you're already playing with fire and deserve to run into this kind of thing.

Comment: This was already clear but I thank you for the specification. How do you answer question 6?

Comment: @jangix Added a bunch of stuff.