# Select Statement is not returning desired results with where clause containing NOT IN operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[datamerge] 
WHERE Timesheet_Id = 'xxx' 
  AND AdminType_Id NOT IN (SELECT [ConfigValue] 
                           FROM [dbo].[adf_Config] 
                           WHERE [ConfigKey] = 'NonBillableEntries')
```

The above query returns 9 rows.

However, if I put in the value of the sub query I get 8 rows as expected:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[datamerge] 
WHERE Timesheet_Id = 'xxx' 
  AND AdminType_Id NOT IN (106, 4, 3, 7, 100, 5, 105)
```

Any idea why this is happening?

**EDIT**

```
timesheet_Id    AdminType_Id
-----------------------------
16530056441     2033563818
16530056441     2033563818
16530056441     2033563818
16530056441     2033563818
16530056441     101
16530056441     101
16530056441     101
16530056441     101
16530056441     4
```

This is the table structure and sample data. I am not expecting the last row to be returned by the query.

And the result of the query

```
SELECT [ConfigValue] 
                           FROM [dbo].[adf_Config] 
                           WHERE [ConfigKey] = 'NonBillableEntries'
```

is

```
ConfigValue
106,4,3,7,100,5,105
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data, the current result(s), and the wanted result - all as formatted text (no images.) Simplify! [mcve].

Comment: What is the AdminType_Id of the row you don't expect?

Comment: @jarlh I updated the question to include the table data

Comment: And what do you get with `SELECT [ConfigValue] FROM [dbo].[adf_Config] WHERE [ConfigKey] = 'NonBillableEntries'`?

Comment: @BrianStork I updated the question

Comment: Do you get a comma-separated string of numbers as a single row for ConfigValue? Or do you get seven, separate rows?

Comment: @BrianStork A single row for configValue separated by a string of numbers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230610/discussion-between-brian-stork-and-mak).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists) You have a nullable column, `NOT IN` doesn't work properly for that

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use not exists. But if you want to use not in then please make sure there is no null value in the list.
Please try this.

```
Select * from [dbo].[datamerge] WHERE Timesheet_Id = 'xxx' AND AdminType_Id NOT IN 
(SELECT [ConfigValue] FROM [dbo].[adf_Config] WHERE [ConfigKey] = 'NonBillableEntries'and ConfigValue is not null)
```

With `not exists` (strongly recommended)

```
Select * from [dbo].[datamerge] d WHERE Timesheet_Id = 'xxx' AND not exists
    (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[adf_Config] a WHERE a.[ConfigKey] = 'NonBillableEntries'and a.ConfigValue =d.AdminType_Id)
```

Comment: I'm a big fan of explicitly accounting for nulls, but a null ConfigValue won't match either an IN nor a NOT IN.

Comment: But a Null in not in () will prevent any row if there is any. 
If you have time the  might have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66846703/sql-left-anti-semi-join-equivalent-query/66846745#66846745

Comment: If this answer helped you then please accept it so that the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but try this:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM        [dbo].[datamerge]   dm
LEFT JOIN   [dbo].[adf_Config]  ac  ON  ac.[ConfigValue]    =   dm.AdminType_Id
                                    AND ac.[ConfigKey]      =   'NonBillableEntries'
WHERE 
        dm.Timesheet_Id     =   'xxx' 
    AND ac.[ConfigValue]    IS  NULL
```